# Security of HTML5 target="_blank" attribute

Tags: html, attributes

*I read something somewhere with the HTML5 target="_blank" attribute security. What's going on there is that this attribute might not be too secure. You rel="noopener" was saying add this attribute as well. Is there anyone to explain what's going on?*

*I tried but I didn't understand much. I would be glad if you help.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reading Google's web.dev article on this topic: [Links to cross-origin destinations are unsafe](https://web.dev/external-anchors-use-rel-noopener/). Here's an excerpt:

> In general, when you use `target="_blank"`, always add `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"`:
>
> ```html
> <a href="https://examplepetstore.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
>   Example Pet Store
> </a>
> ```
>
> - `rel="noopener"` prevents the new page from being able to access the `window.opener` property and ensures it runs in a separate process.
> - `rel="noreferrer"` has the same effect but also prevents the `Referer` header from being sent to the new page. See Link type "noreferrer".